# Do not run an halogen component when an html element is not present

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm absolutely new to purescript and halogen. I'm trying to display an halogen component (myButton) when an html element exists, and do nothing otherwise.

```
displayButton :: Eff (HA.HalogenEffects ()) Unit
displayButton = HA.runHalogenAff do
  containerElement <- HA.selectElement (QuerySelector "#halogen-button")
  case containerElement of
    Nothing -> ???
    Just element -> runUI myButton unit element
```

I don't know what code to put in the *Nothing* clause so that my code type checks and do nothing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pure unit` is the "do nothing" you could put in. You can also use [`for_`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/3.0.0/docs/Data.Foldable#v:for_) to make this a little nicer:

```
for_ containerElement \element ->
  runUI myButton unit element
```

Which, if you take currying into account is the same as:

```
for_ containerElement (runUI myButton unit)
```

Comment: None of the solutions ("pure unit" or the "for_" one) compile. They both give me the error: `Could not match type { query :: forall a. Query a -> Aff ( avar :: AVAR, ref :: REF, exception :: EXCEPTION, dom :: DOM | t2) a, subscribe :: FreeT (Await Message) (Aff ( avar :: AVAR, ref :: REF, exception :: EXCEPTION, dom :: DOM | t2)) Unit -> Aff ( avar :: AVAR, ref :: REF, exception :: EXCEPTION, dom :: DOM | t2) Unit} with Unit`

Comment: There are two `for_`s in purescript. The one from Control.Safely gives the error above. But with the one from Data.Foldable the code compile and seems to be working pertfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Another expression that works for the "do nothing" part is `Data.Monoid.mempty`.